# (JS) calling external .js function with <script> tag

Tags: javascript, php, function

i'm looking to call a function cookiefix() which is located inside main.js and source  is linked at the bottom of my html.

```
echo '<body>';
if(!isset($_COOKIE['clicked'])) {
if(!isset($_COOKIE['count'])) {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">cookiefix();</script>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
, 'document.cookie="count=1";'
, '</script>' ; }  }
```

I was using body onload="" and it worked fine, I know this probably sounds like an uber newby question but i've been searched for the last hour or so and nothing is working.

```
<script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript">cookiefix();</script>
```

I've also tried linking to the source document, didn't work either..
huge thanks to anyone who has a moment

EDIT: If this isn't possible, is there an alternative to 'onload' for anything but ? I was having header issues with cookies and calling it from onload

Comment: `echo` isn't Javascript.

Comment: it's php printing javascript, perhaps I should have labeled it differently

Comment: Good that you know that.  Sometimes people don't.

Comment: You cannot have both a `src` attribute for a `<script>` tag as well as content between the opening and closing tags, AFAIK.

Comment: While it won't break anything, `type="text/javascript"` is generally no longer needed/useful, and is just a waste of time typing.

Comment: thanks paul and greg

Comment: @Paul thats only true for HTML5 doctypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to attach an `onload` event listener to the `<script>` tag.

Such as:

```
<script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript" onload="cookiefix();"></script>
```

`cookiefix()` will be fired once  the script has been successfully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Separate them, order is important:

```
<script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">cookiefix();</script>
```

Comment: already tried that and have top line at bottom of html already, I imagine I wasn't clear.. I have a function inside main.js that i'm trying to call

Comment: @MitchPowell Are you sure you tried this? The second line here omits the *illegal* combination of `src=something.js` and content between the `<script></script>`. As GregL mentioned, that's probably what is wrong in the post up top.

Answer (score 0):

Add to seperate JS file and include in page.

JS:

```
(function(){
        window.onload = cookiefix;
})();
```